# MySQL join columns and count values in the same table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a following table

```
| id | p1_name | p1_score | p2_name | p2_score |
------------------------------------------------
|  1 | aaa     | 2        | bbb     | 3        |
|  1 | ccc     | 1        | ddd     | 7        |
|  1 | ddd     | 5        | aaa     | 8        |
```

What I need is to count all scores for all players and display this in simplier form, like that:

```
| name | score |
----------------
| aaa  |  10   |
| bbb  |   3   |
| ccc  |   1   |
| ddd  |  12   |
```

What would be the SQL syntax to achieve this?

Comment: what have you researched or tried so far? This isn't a free write-my-code service you know...we'll _help_ you with your problem, we won't generally _do it for you_ (unless it's very trivial).

Comment: So far I have tried python code to summarize these values (which works just fine) and now I'm wondering if it can be done purely on DB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Union All` with grouping :

```
select q.name , sum(q.score) as score
  from
    (
    select p1_name as name, p1_score as score
      from tab
    union all 
    select p2_name as name, p2_score
      from tab
    ) q
group by q.name;
```

[***Rextester Demo***](https://rextester.com/TNHTY8840)

Comment: Thank you, great code. Question: Is it necessary to use SUM() in subquery? You and Madhur gave almost identical answers but it seems that in this case SUM() is not counting anything? *select p1_name as name, sum(p1_score) as score*

Comment: @zerocool for your case no, but for repeating `name` values yes :)

Answer (score 0):

We can use `UNION ALL` to combine the names into one column with their corresponding score values. Now, we can use this result-set as a Derived Table, and `GROUP BY` on the `name` and get the `SUM()` of the scores.

```
SELECT 
  dt.name, 
  SUM(dt.score) AS score
FROM 
(
  SELECT
    p1_name AS name, 
    p1_score AS score
  FROM your_table
  UNION ALL
  SELECT
    p2_name AS name, 
    p2_score AS score
  FROM your_table
) AS dt
GROUP BY dt.name
```

**Result**

```
| name | score |
| ---- | ----- |
| aaa  | 10    |
| bbb  | 3     |
| ccc  | 1     |
| ddd  | 12    |
```

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/dqsXYiupvLVzqrUmccNGEq/0)